# Redux Toolkit Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, slice, redux-toolkit

I migrate my app from redux thunk to redux toolkit and while implementing one slice I got an error that says: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

This is my slice:

```
const toastNotificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'toastNotification',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    showToastNotification(state, action) {
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    },
    resetToastNotification() {
      return initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const { showToastNotification, resetToastNotification } = toastNotificationSlice.actions;

export default toastNotificationSlice.reducer;
```

and this is where I do the dispatch:

```
useAppDispatch(showToastNotification({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Not authorized.' }));
```

What can be the problem here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: reset is ok, just show is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is this useAppDispatch? Usually this returns a dispatch method which then needs to be executed. So your execution should look like

```
useAppDispatch()(show....);
```

of course it is better to store the dispatch like

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
...
dispatch(show...);
```

I do not know what is this useAppDispatch so it is only a guess

Comment: It is working this way: useAppDispatch()(show....); Thank you very much!